# Installing Spotlite results in dependencies errors

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

As a newby I am struggling to install downloaded packages. I got one since it is not in the ubuntu lib. called spotlite. I need help to get this 2.0 version installed and it is getting really very complicated with APT commands and so on. I am thinking this should be more simple, it is just an app package......

Anyone? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [search on Repology](https://repology.org/projects/?search=spotlite) this package is available only [for ArchLinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/spotlite). They mark this package as out-of-date since 2019-10-16. If you still need it, let's adapt [ArchLinux PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=spotlite) (or use zip-archive from Spotlite [developers](https://www.spot-net.nl/spotlite) with debs directly) as follows on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://www.spot-net.nl.vfcdn.net/downloads/spotlite/SpotLite%28v2%29Ubuntu.zip
unzip SpotLite\(v2\)Ubuntu.zip
sudo apt-get install ./libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb ./spotlite-amd64.deb
```

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS the problem is harder, it does not have Qt4. So we need to add special [Qt4 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4) first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt-get update
```

and then unpack *libssl0.9.8* and SpotLite to `/usr/local` as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
dpkg -x libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb libssl
sudo cp -arfv libssl/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* /usr/local/lib/
sudo cp -arfv libssl/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/local/lib/
sudo cp -arfv libssl/usr/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
sudo cp -arfv libssl/usr/share/* /usr/local/share/

wget -c http://www.spot-net.nl.vfcdn.net/downloads/spotlite/SpotLite%28v2%29Ubuntu.zip
unzip SpotLite\(v2\)Ubuntu.zip
dpkg -x spotlite-amd64.deb spotlite
sudo cp -arfv spotlite/usr/bin/SpotLite* /usr/local/bin/
sudo cp -arfv spotlite/usr/local/share/* /usr/local/share/
sudo cp -arfv spotlite/usr/share /usr/local/

update-menus
sudo ldconfig
sudo apt-get install libaudio2 libmng2 libodbc1 libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-odbc libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 qtcore4-l10n
```

And then use SpotLite as it was planned.

Comment: Norbert - I suppose that is your name - thanks for the elaborate and fine answer to my question. I was already wondering if it was just my lack of ubuntu knowledge or not. It looks like "not". I will progress as suggested and indeed I am using 20.04.3LTS.

Comment: It is great that you are using 20.04 LTS. See answer above. If it works - you can accept it.

Comment: It runs like a charm, it is still complicated since there is no downloader like in the big brother Spotnet but it works like it should. I just need to use Sabnzbd+ and NZBindex to get a result, no real problem though ;-) What do I do to "accept it" like you suggested?

Comment: There is a gray checkmark at the left of answer, you can click on it:)